# BottomSheetScaffold component isn't constrained after recompose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to have a clean `BottomSheetScaffold` component but when I call a listener to recompose the `BottomSheetScaffold` content, it looks like the component isn't constrained anymore. For example, in the composable function below:

```
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@Composable
fun HomeScreen() {
    val bottomSheetScaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(
        bottomSheetState = BottomSheetState(BottomSheetValue.Collapsed)
    )
    val (buttonText, setButtonText) = remember {
        mutableStateOf("Button")
    }
    var sheetPeekHeightValue by remember {
        mutableStateOf(50.0)
    }
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    BottomSheetScaffold(
        scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
        sheetContent = {
            Box(
                Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(200.dp)
            ) {
                Text(text = "Hello from sheet")
            }
        }, sheetPeekHeight = sheetPeekHeightValue.dp
    ) {
        Button(onClick = {
            coroutineScope.launch {

                if (bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.isCollapsed) {
                    bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.expand()
                } else {
                    bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.collapse()
                }
            }
        }) {
            Text(text = buttonText)
        }
        Button(onClick = {
            setButtonText(buttonText + ".")
            //sheetPeekHeightValue += .01
        }){Text("Changing Text Button")}
    }
}
```

The "buttonText" button works until I click the "Changing Text Button" button.

If the line `sheetPeekHeightValue += .01` is not commented, it will recompose the BottomSheetScaffold however this is not clean.

---

Is recomposing in `BottomSheetScaffold` content a good practice?
If it is, how am I supposed to do this properly?

Comment: Looks like a bug. I was able to reproduce it in Compose `1.0.4`, but in the latest alpha `1.1.0-alpha06` it seems fixed.

Comment: I upgrated the compose version and it is fixed now thank you @PhilipDukhov !